# Remove all characters before a pipe and also remove pipe using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, e-commerce

Hi I'm at work and I'm working in pandas and trying to remove all characters before this pipe in this csv file. Also replacing semi colons with a pipe would also be very helpful.

```
Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xXlarge; 
Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xlarge; 
Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge; 
Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge;
```

Here's what I've been trying but am having trouble with escaping the pipe.

```
df['Variations'] = df['Variations'].replace(regex=r'/\|$', value='')
```

I need to get this

```
Medium|Large|Xlarge|2Xlarge|3Xlarge|4Xlarge|5xXlarge 
Medium|Large|Xlarge|2Xlarge|3Xlarge|4Xlarge|5xlarge
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output for those examples, preferably not in a screenshot (something easy to copy/paste)

Comment: Probably, `data['Variations'].str.replace(r'^[^|]*\|\s*', '').str.replace(';', '|', regex=False)`

Comment: What about the lines like `Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge;`?  No output expected at all?

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. I just need To get rid of last pipe at end. Thank you|

Comment: df['Variations'] = df['Variations'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-2]) I added this from another post thank you again.

Comment: You do not need to map anything, just use my solution below, it does everything you need. Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
data['Variations'] = data['Variations'].str.replace(r'^[^|]*\|\s*|;\s*$', '').str.replace('\s*;\s*', '|')
```

The `.replace(r'^[^|]*\|\s*|;\s*$', '')` will remove all substrings from start of string till the first `|` including it and any subsequent whitespace chars and final `;` (with any 0+ whitespace at the end) and `.replace('\s*;\s*', '|')` will replace all `;` with any whitespaces around the semi-colon with a pipe char.